# How to run serve_app in a Tornado project

Tags: tornado

I am currently working through this tutorial ([Tutorial](https://opensource.com/article/18/6/tornado-framework#:%7E:text=We%20can%20make%20sure%20this%20all%20works%20by%20running%20our%20app%20with%20the%20serve_app%20command%20we%20enabled%20in%20the%20setup.py.%20Check%20http%3A//localhost%3A8888/%20and%20see%20that%20it%20says%20%22Hello%2C%20world!%22)) on developing a Tornado project.  After setting up setup.py, views.py, and init.py it says:
"We can make sure this all works by running our app with the serve_app command we enabled in the setup.py. Check http://localhost:8888/ and see that it says "Hello, world!"

I have tried running

```
$ python3 setup.py serve_app
```

however, I get the error

```
error: invalid command 'serve_app'
```

How do I correctly run this application?

My current project setup is as follows

```
tornado_todo/
    setup.py
    todo/
        models.py
        views.py
        __init__.py
```

My setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

requires = [
    'tornado',
    'tornado-sqlalchemy',
    'psychopg2',
]

setup(
    name='tornado_todo',
    version='0.0',
    description='A To-Do List built with Tornado',
    author='Jake',
    author_email='mulherje@gmail.com',
    keywords='web tornado',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=requires,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'serve_app = todo:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

**init**.py

```
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.options import define, options
from tornado.web import Application
from todo.views import HelloWorld

define('port', default=8888, help='port to listen on')

def main():
    """Construct and serve the tornado application."""
    app = Application([
        ('/', HelloWorld)
    ])
    http_server = HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    print('Listening on http://localhost:%i' % options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

views.py

```
from tornado.web import RequestHandler


class HelloWorld(RequestHandler):
    """Print 'Hello, World!' as the response body."""

    def get(self):
        """Handle a GET request for saying Hello World!."""
        self.write("Hellow, world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `console_scripts` lines in `setup.py` cause a script named `serve_app` to be created when you run `setup.py install` or `setup.py develop .` (this is missing from the linked tutorial, which seems like a mistake). So you can run `setup.py develop .` and then `serve_app`. (note that this is not a workflow I've ever used myself; I use a pip requirements.txt instead of setup.py when defining dependencies for my applications. But I believe that's what you need to make this tutorial work)